# how many permutation of the letters PQRSTUVWX contain the string VWX or WX

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I know how to calculate each task like the following
7! + 8!
but I am not sure how to subtract the overlapping part
usually, it will the (or) parts is between distinct string, but in this example, they share 2 letters
how do I solve this?

Comment: If the permutation contains $VWX$ then it automatically contains $WX$ so you just need to count the permutations that contain $WX$, no?

Comment: but then it won't have the V always, right ? then you can't count it for the 1st condition

Comment: I don't understand.  You said "or", so I only need to pass one of the tests.  Or did you mean to use the "Exclusive Or", in which case you are asking for those permutations which contain $WX$ but which do not contain $VWX$,  If the latter, you really need to clarify that in your post...in standard English "or" is non-exclusive.

Comment: I don't know that's how the question came exactly

Comment: Well, it's your problem.  My guess is what I wrote in my first comment...that is, I'd assume that the non-exclusive or was intended.  Maybe solve both interpretations!  Good practice.  Using the non-exclusive or, you are just looking for the permutations that contain $WX$.  Count those.  Then assume that the non-exclusive or was intended, so you have to subtract off those that contain $VWX$.  Neither computation is difficult.

Comment: yeah I don't think it meant the exclusive-or otherwise it would state it thanks

Answer (score 0):

If repetition is not allowed and order isn't important, then you have $6!$ ways to do the string.

But note that, if you have the events

$E_1$: The string contains WX
&
$E_2$: The string contains VWX

We have that $E_1 \cup E_2= E_1$
So, I think, it is enough to say in your title that '... contain the string WX'